# How to Query from 2 table with criteria like this

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Stock` and table `Request`.

For example :

**Stock**

```
Warehouse | Item | Qty | Status
A         | Pen  | 200 | Available
A         | Pen  | 800 | Hold
```

**Request**

```
Warehouse | Item | Qty 
A         | Pen  | 500
```

My question is how to get Qty from Stock with logic?

`SUM Qty stock Minus SUM Qty from Request`

example (1000 - 500)

And should return 200 Qty from Stock.

And so on if Qty from Request changes to 600 then (1000 - 600) and should return 100 Qty from Stock.

Comment: Hi @ChandraFebrico can you explain the logic?

Answer (score 1):

As per your expectation stock calculation looks like below

```
-- SQL SERVER
SELECT s.warehouse, s.item, (s.stk_qty - r.req_qty) total_qty
     , CASE WHEN r.rem_req_qty > 0
               THEN s.stk_avail - r.rem_req_qty
            ELSE s.stk_avail
       END available_stock
FROM (SELECT warehouse
           , item
           , SUM(qty) stk_qty
           , SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Available' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) stk_avail
      FROM stock
      GROUP BY warehouse
             , item) s
INNER JOIN (SELECT p.warehouse
                 , p.item
                 , SUM(p.qty) req_qty
                 , SUM(CASE WHEN p.row_num = 1 THEN p.qty ELSE 0 END) first_req_qty
                 , SUM(CASE WHEN p.row_num > 1 THEN p.qty ELSE 0 END) rem_req_qty
            FROM (SELECT warehouse
                       , item
                       , qty
                       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY warehouse, item ORDER BY warehouse) row_num
                  FROM request) p
            GROUP BY p.warehouse
                   , p.item) r
        ON s.warehouse = r.warehouse
       AND s.item = r.item;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba290a1a7095195519be0f6d267e42e0

Another way when available stock never negative (if negative then 0)

```
-- SQL SERVER
SELECT s.warehouse, s.item, (s.stk_qty - r.req_qty) total_qty
     , CASE WHEN r.rem_req_qty > 0 
               THEN CASE WHEN (s.stk_avail - r.rem_req_qty) > 0
                            THEN s.stk_avail - r.rem_req_qty
                         ELSE 0
                    END
            ELSE s.stk_avail
       END available_stock
FROM (SELECT warehouse
           , item
           , SUM(qty) stk_qty
           , SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Available' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) stk_avail
      FROM stock
      GROUP BY warehouse
             , item) s
INNER JOIN (SELECT p.warehouse
                 , p.item
                 , SUM(p.qty) req_qty
                 , SUM(CASE WHEN p.row_num = 1 THEN p.qty ELSE 0 END) first_req_qty
                 , SUM(CASE WHEN p.row_num > 1 THEN p.qty ELSE 0 END) rem_req_qty
            FROM (SELECT warehouse
                       , item
                       , qty
                       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY warehouse, item ORDER BY warehouse) row_num
                  FROM request) p
            GROUP BY p.warehouse
                   , p.item) r
        ON s.warehouse = r.warehouse
       AND s.item = r.item;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2449b729e99c69ee86c207f7dbeed465

Comment: Hi @ChandraFabrico please check my query and let me know if any query regard this. Will stock quantity become negative?

Answer (score 0):

The join condition between the tables is assumed to be between both the 'Warehouse' and 'Item' columns.  Something like this

```
with sum_cte(Warehouse, Item, sum_qty) as (
    select Warehouse, Item, sum(qty) sum_qty
    from Stock
    group by Warehouse, Item)
select s.Warehouse, s.Item, (s.sum_qty-r.Qty) Qty
from sum_cte s
     join Request r on s.Warehouse=r.Warehouse
                       and s.Item=r.Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a very simple way to solve this, using `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT s.Warehouse, s.Item, SUM(s.Qty - r.Qty) 'Qty'
FROM (SELECT s.Warehouse, s.Item, SUM(s.Qty) Qty FROM stock s GROUP BY s.Item, s.Warehouse) s
INNER JOIN (SELECT r.Warehouse, r.Item, SUM(r.Qty) Qty FROM request r GROUP BY r.Item, r.Warehouse) r ON s.item = r.item AND s.warehouse = r.warehouse
GROUP BY s.Item, s.Warehouse
```

Check demo on [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a33dbc7e9f5384bebda7bfb8a586697d).

You will see on demo, that after 100 Qty in `Request` table, final sum is lower by 100 Qty.